# How to calculate the frame.size.width

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

In my case to calculate a UILabel frame.origin.x to make it on the right side with code below:

```
writerNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - writerNameLabel.frame.size.width - 80.......)

NSLog(@" writerNameLabel frame width: %f",writerNameLabel.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" cell frame width: %f",cell.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" cell - writerNameLabel frame width: %f",cell.frame.size.width - writerNameLabel.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" writerNameLabel frame x: %f",writerNameLabel.frame.origin.x);


2012-08-17 14:43:36.895 writerNameLabel frame width: 38.000000
2012-08-17 14:43:36.899 cell frame width: 320.000000
2012-08-17 14:43:36.902 cell - writerNameLabel frame width: 282.000000
2012-08-17 14:43:36.904 writerNameLabel frame x: 240.000000

----

2012-08-17 14:43:36.924 writerNameLabel frame width: 102.000000
2012-08-17 14:43:36.928 cell frame width: 320.000000
2012-08-17 14:43:36.931 cell - writerNameLabel frame width: 218.000000
2012-08-17 14:43:36.934 writerNameLabel frame x: 240.000000
```

The problem is that this

> cell.frame.size.width - writerNameLabel.frame.size.width

part in my calculation doesn't work, it only return the value of

> cell.frame.size.width - 80

, why? Did I do anything wrong?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a frame already set for your label? If not, it's {0, 0, 0, 0} by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value of writerNameLabel.frame.size.width is 0 at that time.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that you haven't initially set the label's frame thus, by default, it's `{ 0, 0, 0, 0`}, that's why it's ineffective in the calculation.

Comment: Sorry about that, I deleted the post. I misunderstood what the OP was asking.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle no worries, mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

the frame's default value is {0, 0, 0, 0} by default

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize the writerNameLabel? You should use initWithFrame, otherwise it has size (0,0).

Just Info:

I assume you are using UITableViewCell because name of your variable is cell :)
In that case, it would be better if you use cell.contentView.frame.size.width instead of cell.frame.size.width. So you can prevent overlapping  writerNameLabel with accessory view of the cell. Easiest approach would be using the labels, which are already(by default) on UITableViewCell instance.